# Unable to connect Azure Mysql using Nodejs

Tags: mysql, node.js, azure, express

I came across this issue today I tried to connect and retreive data in Azure Database for MySQL by using nodejs, so now I'm just tried to test the connection but it doesnt work.

*Ps: database is exists*

eg:

```
const db = mysql.createConnection({
host: '50.xx.xx.xx',
user: 'admin',
password: 'xxxx',
database: 'admin',
port: 3306
})
```

[image]

Comment: if the message tells you that a database `admin` doesn't exist, it is actually is so, so go to azure and let you show all databases and choose te one you need or else create the database

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Depending on how MySQL was installed, it is possible that the default admin database was NOT created.
- You may have to look for whitespace in database name. See if white space has been added in front or after database name.
- Database must be created first.
- create it in mysql with

```sql
mysql> create database admin
```